# 'ws = cat.get_workspace('rake_ereke')' code works locally, but on server raise Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]

Tags: django, urllib3

[Here when problem occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXWNU.png)

> ConnectionError at /backends/profile/
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='geo.egistic.kz', port=8081): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/workspaces.xml (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))

I am trying to connect geoserver on my server. Code works properly on my computer without errors, however on server it gives me this error
[Error image, which appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9rQF.png)

`
    def profile(request):

```
    requests = request.user.backendrequests_set.all()

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', {
           'backend_request_form': form,
            'requests': requests
        })
```

requests = request.user.backendrequests_set.all()- here exception appears because of **_set.all()**
I have surfed the Internet, however other similar errors are not my case
Thank you for any help

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with _set. The error is basically telling you that it cannot reach the server you are trying to get data from. Did you try to ping the resource from you server to see if its reachable?

Comment: devdob, I have identified the problem, yeah you are right. This site 'https://geo.egistic.kz:8081' and backend are located in same server. may be problem is here? Because, in past the site 'https://geo.egistic.kz:8081' was 'http://178.91.253.19:8081', but in server it has another ip '10.10.13.16'. I always changed between these two before pull in server. Now it has static domain name in and out of server -> "geo.egistic.kz"

Comment: So is it working now?

Comment: does this geo.egistic.kz server need credentials? is it your server? or is it an external service you are using?

Comment: https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py/issues/1586

Comment: What is the setting set to now? If its hosted local, why is your url still pointing geo.egistic.kz instead of localhost?

Comment: yeah, I have edited link to problem 'Here when problem occurs'. Can you look at that? It means it can connect '''geo.egistic.kz:8081", however can not get workspace from it

Comment: How do you know it can connect to it but not get a workspace. The connection wasnt even established, it times out. Instantiating the object does not mean a connection was done.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is in server other host name is used, as in docker containers. Thus I could not find proper hostname in server